# Failed to build index for unexpected reason in Apache phoenix

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

> I have installed phoenix-5 on Hbase-2.2.2 and Hadoop-3.2.1 when I
>   create an index on a table, insertion time I get the following error. does
>   anybody know what the problem is?

```
try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("create  Index  myIndex on city(name)");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.builder.IndexBuildingFailureException: Failed to build index for unexpected reason!
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.util.IndexManagementUtil.rethrowIndexingException(IndexManagementUtil.java:206)
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer.preBatchMutate(Indexer.java:351)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$28.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1019)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$28.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1016)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.CoprocessorHost$ObserverOperationWithoutResult.callObserver(CoprocessorHost.java:551)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.CoprocessorHost.execOperation(CoprocessorHost.java:625)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.preBatchMutate(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1016)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$MutationBatchOperation.prepareMiniBatchOperations(HRegion.java:3675)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.doMiniBatchMutate(HRegion.java:4091)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.batchMutate(HRegion.java:4045)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.batchMutate(HRegion.java:3976)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:1042)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:974)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:937)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2737)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:42202)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:338)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:318)
        Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.covered.data.IndexMemStore$1 overrides final method compare.(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/Cell;Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/Cell;)I
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.covered.data.IndexMemStore.(IndexMemStore.java:82)
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.covered.LocalTableState.(LocalTableState.java:57)
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.covered.NonTxIndexBuilder.getIndexUpdate(NonTxIndexBuilder.java:52)
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.builder.IndexBuildManager.getIndexUpdate(IndexBuildManager.java:90)
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer.preBatchMutateWithExceptions(Indexer.java:503)
            at org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer.preBatchMutate(Indexer.java:348)
            ... 18 more
        : 1 time, servers with issues: ubuntu,16020,1580881208169

Comment: Can you please edit the post to add what commands you used and !describe the table you are trying to create this index on?

Comment: I have a table named "city" with 15 columns .the problem is not with code I get this error even with the sqlline.py.